# Unable to update mongodb document with nested object property from node api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nested, mongoose-schema, put

I have the following mongodb document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ee95b41ca023a3deb252ef2"),
    "uid" : "jdoe",
    "name" : "John Doe",
    "employee_hire_date" : "2012-06-20",
    "three_month_review_target" : "2012-09-20",
    "six_month_review_target" : "2012-12-20",
    "three_month_review_status" : {
        "is_scheduled" : null,
        "is_team_member_emailed" : null,
        "is_review_executed" : null,
    },
    "six_month_review_status" : {
        "is_scheduled" : null,
        "is_team_member_emailed" : null,
        "is_review_executed" : null,
    }
}
```

I would like to update the `three_month_review_status.is_scheduled` nested property to `true`. I am using a put request to accomplish this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Reviews = require('../modules/reviews/models/reviews');

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.put('/api/reviews/isScheduled', async (req, res) => {
        console.log('body', req.body)
        console.log('uid', req.body.uid)
        console.log('is_scheduled', req.body.three_month_review_status.is_scheduled)
        Reviews.findOneAndUpdate( { 'uid': req.body.uid }, { $set: { 'three_month_review_status.is_scheduled': req.body.is_scheduled }}, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error', err)
            }
             else {
                console.log('updated', result);
                res.status(200).send(result);
            }
        } )
    });
}
```

To test this, I execute this PUT request through Postman with the following request body:

```
{
    "uid": "jdoe",
    "three_month_review_status": {
        "is_scheduled": "true"
    }
}
```

However, when the request gets executed, the other two nested objects are removed and `is_scheduled` remains null. This is the document after the request is executed:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ee95b41ca023a3deb252ef2"),
    "uid" : "jdoe",
    "name" : "John Doe",
    "employee_hire_date" : "2012-06-20",
    "three_month_review_target" : "2012-09-20",
    "six_month_review_target" : "2012-12-20",
    "three_month_review_status" : {
        "is_scheduled" : null
    },
    "six_month_review_status" : {
        "is_scheduled" : null,
        "is_team_member_emailed" : null,
        "is_review_executed" : null,
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Here is my reviewsSchema for more context:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const reviewsSchema = new Schema({
    uid: String,
    name: String,
    employee_hire_date: String,
    three_month_review_target: String,
    six_month_review_target: String,
    three_month_review_status: {
        is_scheduled: Boolean,
        is_team_member_emailed: Boolean,
        is_review_executed: Boolean,
    },
    six_month_review_status: {
        is_scheduled: Boolean,
        is_team_member_emailed: Boolean,
        is_review_executed: Boolean,
    },
})

const Reviews = model('review', reviewsSchema);

module.exports = Reviews;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mongoose you don't need to specify the `$set`. Also based on the sample `JSON` that you send from the postman instead of `req.body.is_scheduled` you need to provide `req.body.three_month_review_status.is_scheduled` in the query. Also, need to add `{new: true}` if you want the `findOneAndUpdate` to return the updated document

So you can update the query like

```js
Reviews.findOneAndUpdate(
  { uid: req.body.uid },
  {
    "three_month_review_status.is_scheduled":
      req.body.three_month_review_status.is_scheduled,
  },
  { new: true },
  (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error", err);
    } else {
      console.log("updated", result);
      res.status(200).send(result);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I also found out that the request will remove the other nested properties if they are set to `null`. Setting them with an initial value of `false` keeps the properties there after the request is executed.